# Endless Upgrade loop for Ubuntu/NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-20.04

I am looking to upgrade my NodeJS version to 18.20 or later, but am hitting a snag where it is requiring me to have an upgraded libC (2.28+ where I have 2.27 today), which in turn requires upgrading Ubuntu, which won't upgrade without NodeJS....so I am stumped.

Here is the initial issue I had when trying to upgrade NodeJS:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
r-base-core : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.29) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is to be installed

Any ideas? What am I missing? I am trying to get things in order as I have a VM with an Ubuntu instance that I use for Homebridge, and am not able to get Homebridge fully updated without a nodeJS version of 18.2 or higher.

Any thoughts or insights appreciated. Hoping its something simple I'm missing

I have tried to upgrade both nodeJS and Ubuntu, running into an issue where either will not update without the other.